# Concatination of 2 Data inside a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

how to concatenate 2 data inside a combobox? here's my code:

```
private void loadPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            using (var ctx = new Service()) {
                try {
                    var query1 = from prod in ctx.products select prod.brand;
                    comboBox1.ItemsSource = query1.ToList();
                    var query4 = from hosp in ctx.hospitals select hosp.name;
                    comboBox4.ItemsSource = query4.ToList();
                    var query5 = (from cont in ctx.contactPersons select new { cont.lastName, cont.firstName }).First();
                    var fName = (query5.lastName + ", " + query5.firstName);
                    comboBox5.ItemsSource = fName.ToList();
                } catch {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR 404: Database Not Found");
                }
            }
        }
```

my mockup data is test(lastname) and test(firstname). it kinda funny since it outputs this:

> t
>
> e
>
> s
>
> t
>
> ,
>
> t
>
> e
>
> s
>
> t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ItemSource expect an IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx), so you need to pass it an enumerable. but when you have a string and you ToList() it, you turn it to a list of char. so, you need to create an enumerable and add the the string you want. 
for example:

```
comboBox5.ItemsSource = new List<String>() {fName}
```

or, in your code example, just drop the "First()":

```
var query5 = ctx.contactPersons.Select(p => p.LastName + ", " + p.FirstName).ToList();
```

and you'll end up with an enumerable which you can set as an ItemSource for the combo box

Comment: its throwing me a this `Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.dll`

Comment: you need to enumerate the linq query to perform the action - add ToList() in the end of the query - my bad

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
 void loadPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            using (var ctx = new Service()) {
                try {
                    var query1 = from prod in ctx.products select prod.brand;
                    comboBox1.ItemsSource = query1.ToList();
                    var query4 = from hosp in ctx.hospitals select hosp.name;
                    comboBox4.ItemsSource = query4.ToList();
                    var query5 = (from cont in ctx.contactPersons select new { fName = cont.lastName + ", " + cont.firstName });
                    comboBox5.ItemsSource = query5.ToList();
                } catch {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR 404: Database Not Found");
                }
            }
        }
```

`fName.ToList()` basically is generating a list of individual characters in `fName` (which is a string in your instance).

Comment: thanks for replicating my code and implementing your solution on it it makes my life more easier

Comment: tho the item that is listed now in the combobox is 
> {fNAme = test, test} 
but i did concatenate but whats with the fname and the braces

Comment: and im also planning to do it to query1 but it doesnt seem to work if there are 2 of em there